# How to get whole superscript numbers using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to store all the occurrences of superscript numbers (which is a citation key numbers relevant to references) into an array.

**Sample:**

Some example citation<sup>2</sup> another citation with<sup>31,16,83,9-15</sup>
and some more citation<sup>18,2,30</sup>

**Expected output:**

```
stored_content=[2,31,16,83,9-15,18,2,30]
```

When I find superscript numbers it searches as single digit. For example, it finds `18` as `1` and `8` seperately. I tried as below:

```vb
Sub Sample()
    Dim c As Range
    
    Set c = ActiveDocument.Content
    c.Find.ClearFormatting
    
    With c.Find
         .Forward = True             'move forward only
    .Highlight = False
    .Font.superscript = True
      
     .Text = "^#"
     .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    c.Find.Execute
    While c.Find.Found
        Debug.Print c.Text
        c.Find.Execute
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you require.

I did away with the `Find.Text = "^#"` and then found any SuperScript Font and then evaluated the `FoundText` to no have numbers and then I splits the found text with the comma delimter to get the individual citations.

Please note that you will need Regular Expressions included in your Library. In VBA Select Tools and then References.

```
 Sub SomeSub()

      Dim RegExpFind As Object
      'You will need Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions added to your Library
      Set RegExpFind = New RegExp

      Dim DocumentContent As Range
      Set DocumentContent = ThisDocument.Content

      Dim FoundText As String
      Dim FoundTextArray As Variant
      Dim ArrayPosition As Long

      With DocumentContent.Find
           .Font.Superscript = True
           .Text = ""
           .Replacement.Text = ""
           .Forward = True
           'Stops the Find after reaching the end of the document
           .Wrap = wdFindStop
           .Format = True
           .MatchCase = False
           .MatchWholeWord = False
           .MatchWildcards = False
           .MatchSoundsLike = False
           .MatchAllWordForms = False

           Do While .Execute

                If .Found = True Then

                     'Because your citations do not have spaces between the numbers and only a comma
                     FoundText = DocumentContent.Text

                     With RegExpFind

                          .Pattern = "[a-zA-z]"
                          .IgnoreCase = True
                          'If there are no letters
                          If Not .Test(FoundText) Then

                               If Len(FoundText) <= 2 Then

                                    Debug.Print FoundText

                               Else

                                    FoundTextArray = Split(FoundText, ",")

                                    For ArrayPosition = 0 To UBound(FoundTextArray)

                                         'Here is where can then do other things with the numbers between the commas
                                         Debug.Print FoundTextArray(ArrayPosition)

                                    Next ArrayPosition

                               End If 'Ending Len(FoundText) <= 2

                          End If 'Ending .Test(FoundText)

                     End With 'Ending RegExpFind

                End If 'Ending .Found = True

           Loop

      End With 'Ending DocumentContent.Find

 End Sub
```